# Concatening variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array that I want to loop with a for.

```
for(var j = 0; j < outPutData.length; j++)
{
    if(outPutData[j].pregunta1==1) {  }
}
```

pregunta1, pregunta2, etc. are some of the variables.

If I print the value of **outPutData[j].pregunta1** with an alert() it shows the correct value, but when I try:

```
for(var j = 0; j < outPutData.length; j++)
{
    if(outPutData[j].pregunta+j==1) {  }
```

OR

```
    if(outPutData[j].pregunta+""+j==2) {  }
}
```

an error is shown. Why?

What I expect to have is

```
outPutData[j].pregunta1
outPutData[j].pregunta2
outPutData[j].pregunta3
... (more till 200)...
outPutData[j].pregunta200
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably just be making `pregunta` an array though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
outPutData[j]['pregunta' + j]
```

you can access properties of object by string using `[]`:

```
var obj = {prop: "value"}

var a = obj.prop;
// is the same as
var b = obj['prop'];
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem!